# Easiest way to deploy OSGi framework from Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, osgi, equinox

I am developing a server with Jetty (servlet container). I am successfully running the server within Eclipse with an osgi-framework run configuration. Everything fine.

What is the best way to export this run configuration so that I have a valid `config.ini` and all plugins (the workspace bundles and the ones from my target platform) and am able to run the osgi-framework without Eclipse IDE running.

I tried to make a product to get the `config.ini` and all the bundles but I cannot run the framework with `java -jar org.eclipse.osgi_3.6.2.R36x_v20110210.jar`.

It is not finding the bundles in the `plugin` folder, because obviously the names do not match exactly (e.g.: `com.mine.at-3.3.-3234234.jar` instead of `com.mine.at.jar`)
There are about 150 bundles and I do not want to edit the `config.ini` manually.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

What worked pretty well for me was to make a new product, based on the (working) run configuration, and export the product. That project should then be 'runnable', or at least pretty close.

Did you try that?

Hope it helps, Frank